# How to serve images stored in a cassandra database?

Tags: django, apache, nginx, cassandra

For a django project, I plan to store jpegs into a cassandra database.
What is the best way to serve images for a web site ?
I already planned to build my own wsgi module, but is there a better way : does a nginx or apache module exists for that ?

Answer (score 3):

We serve small files ( < 5 MB ) from Cassandra using PHP with a caching layer (both disk and in-memory, e.g. [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/)).

Answer (score 1):

Astyanax supports file streaming into and out of cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

You can use openresty and the [Lua CQL client](https://github.com/jbochi/lua-resty-cassandra/blob/master/README.md) that I have developed.

Usage would be something like this:

```
cassandra = require("cassandra")
local session = cassandra.new()
session:set_timeout(1000)
assert(session:connect("127.0.0.1", 9042))
assert(session:set_keyspace("images"))
local rows, err = session:execute("SELECT * from chunks where chunk_id = ?", {chunk})
if not rows or #rows == 0 then
  return ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_NOT_FOUND)
end
local data = rows[1].data
ngx.header.content_type = "image/jpeg"
ngx.header.content_length = #data
ngx.print(data)
```